# Why is "throw null" not creating a compilation error in Java?

Tags: java, exception, null

```
class ThrowNull {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        throw null;
    }
}
```

We know that rule for throw is `throw ThrowableInstance;`, where `ThrowableInstance` must be an object of type Throwable or a subclass of Throwable.

Simple types, such as int or char, as well as non-Throwable classes, such as String and Object, cannot be used as exceptions. `null` is a special Java literal which represents a null value.

So why would `throw null;` compile in this code?

Comment: Why should it result in a compile-time error?

Comment: Although this is not flagged as a problem by the Java Compiler itself at the present time (unless the language specification changes at some future time), it clearly is a candidate for static checkers like "Sonar" to root out and point out to the developer. Maybe the developer wanted to write "return null"...

Comment: We know that the rule is that the result of calling `String a() {return null}` must be an object of (sub)class or String. Simple classes, like Throwable or BigInteger cannot be used as Strings.  Null is a special Java literal which represents a null value. Then why `return null` is not creating any compile time error?????!!!! I am exposing your double standards here. Why do you complain about `throw null` but not about `return null`? I cannot upvote your question therefore. It is too localized by means of double standards.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18), a `throw` statement is defined as:

```
throw Expression
```

And if the `Expression` evaluates to `null`, then a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Specifically,

> If evaluation of the *Expression* completes normally, producing a `null` value, then an instance *V'* of class `NullPointerException` is created and thrown instead of `null`.

Since `NullPointerException` extends `RuntimeException`, it is an unchecked exception. This could explain why there's no compile-time error reported from this construct.

Comment: so null somehow converts to a NullPointer Exception, but what if I throw a String or a number? I gives runtime exception and says ```No exception of type String can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
``` why is it so?

Comment: It's not that null "somehow converts" to a NPE. The language specification says that when `throw` gets a null value, it needs to create and throw a NullPointerException. So it does. The spec says that throw must be given "1) a variable or value of a reference type which is assignable (§5.2) to the type Throwable, or 2) the null reference". Anything else will result in a compiler error.

Comment: It's also not clear what you would expect the language to do. A NullPointerException is commonly thrown when a value is expected but null is received (see java.io.File's constructor, for example). There's no obviously *right* behavior, though, for throwing an arbitrary object. (Would it generate an exception? Which one? Checked or unchecked? Or would you expect to catch an arbitrary object too? Would you `catch(String s)`, or `catch("oops")`?) Letting the compiler reject unclear things is often better than having potentially surprising behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

There are many things a compiler doesn't check, it assumes you do things for a good reason which it might not know about.  What it does try to prevent is the common mistakes developers make.

It is possible some one thinks this is a good short hand for

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

---

```
Integer i = null;
try {
    i.intValue();
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    System.err.println("Caught NPE");
    npe.printStackTrace();
}
```

and

```
try {
    throw null;
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    System.err.println("Caught NPE");
    npe.printStackTrace();
}
```

prints in Java 6 update 38

```
Caught NPE
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: @DanielWerner All exceptions and Errors and catchable even OutOfmemoryError and ThreadDeath. ;) See my example.

Answer (score 3):

I think because Null can be cast in to any type of reference.so in compile time its nothing wrong if you are throwing null instead of throwable.

Comment: Exactly. Your method, that returns a String, may return null. Why string variable can be null but Throwable variable cannot? OP definitely is either short-sighted (x)or exercises the double standards.

Comment: This might sound nicely, but it isn't true. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In generel, and not just throw. Any object variable can be assigned null. So we can see that throw is not a special case. Should it be? maybe. Is it consistent? Yes.