# Why is throw null not a compiler warning?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

Why is throw null not a compiler warning in C#?

I saw some code which had a `throw null;` in it.  This causes a new `NullReferenceException`  to be thrown.

Why would the compiler not flag this with a warning?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does C# let you throw null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195764/why-does-c-sharp-allow-you-to-throw-null) . Related : [in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591910/why-throw-null-is-not-creating-compilation-error-in-java)

Comment: For the same reason that you don't have a warning label on a microwave oven that says it is not suitable to dry the poodle.