# Handling Checked and unchecked exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I have below class with one method which throws Checked Exception.

```
public class Sample{

 public String getName() throws CustomException{

  //Some code
   //this method contacts some third party library and that can throw RunTimeExceptions

}

}
```

### CustomException.java

```
public class CustomException Extends Exception{
 //Some code


}
```

Now in another class i need to call above the method and handle exceptions.

```
public String getResult() throws Exception{
  try{
  String result = sample.getName();
   //some code
  }catch(){
     //here i need to handle exceptions
   }
  return result;
}
```

My requirement is:

`sample.getName()` can throw CustomException and it can also throw `RunTimeExceptions`.

In the catch block, I need to catch the exception. If the exception that is caught is `RunTimeException` then I need to check if the `RunTimeException`  is an instance of `SomeOtherRunTimeException`. If so, I should throw **null** instead.

If `RunTimeException`  is not an instance of `SomeOtherRunTimeException` then I simply need to rethrow the same run time exception.

If the caught exception is a `CustomException` or any other Checked Exception, then I need to rethrow the same. How can I do that?

Comment: Erm, you can't throw `null`? Do you mean to *return* `null`?

Comment: @meriton You can `throw null`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576922/why-can-i-throw-null-in-java)

Comment: Since `null` isn't an instance of `Throwable`, it can not be thrown, or caught. While `throw null` compiles, it doesn't actually throw `null`, but a new `NullPointerException` (when I say "throw x", I mean what the spec calls "complete abruptly, the reason being a throw with value x".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
catch(RuntimeException r)
{
     if(r instanceof SomeRunTimeException)
       throw null; 
       else throw r;
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
     throw e;
}
```

Note: `Exception` catches all the exceptions. That's why it is placed at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
public String getResult() throws Exception {
    String result = sample.getName(); // move this out of the try catch
    try {
        // some code
    } catch (SomeOtherRunTimeException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

All other checked and unchecked exceptions will be propagated. There is no need to catch and rethrow.