# Can Java throw a null reference to an exception?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Consider this code:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (MyException e){
    /*Can e be null here?*/
}
```

Given that `null` in Java is a typed null reference, is it ever possible that the catch block above will be entered with `e` as `null`?

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/17576922/2219371

Comment: How much investment would it have been to actually write `throw null;` and see for yourself?

Comment: Because, for one thing, I'd be concerned as to the *type* of null I'd be throwing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e` will never be `null`. Even if `null` gets thrown somewhere for some reason, `e` will just be a `NullPointerException`.