# Throwing null in Java

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

Working on `Android` I bumped into something like this:

```
    try {
         return someMethodThatThrowsExceptionA();
        } catch (ExceptionBthatExtendsExceptionA e) {
            // e is null but caught here.
        } catch (ExceptionA e) {
            // e is also null when caught.
        }
    }
```

While I still need to dig out the reasons why the exception is thrown inside many method calls, there are two very surprising things here for me:

- The `Exception` is caught, but somehow is `null`. As per [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378147/can-java-throw-a-null-reference-to-an-exception?lq=1) and [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576922/why-can-i-throw-null-in-java?lq=1) , I thought that throwing `null` was impossible.
- The `Exception` is catched by a `catch block` for a `Subclass` of the `Exception` that the method throws ( `ExceptionBthatExtendsExceptionA` ).

If I remove the catch block for `ExceptionBthatExtendsExceptionA`, the `Exception` is caught by the `ExceptionA` `catch block`, but is also `null`.

Could you explain me

- How a `method` is throwing `null` without creating a `NullPointerException`? ----> Not possible as per [Java's specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18).
- How is a `null` `Exception` correctly catched (casted?) to a specific `catch block`? How can can the `catch block` recognize that `null` is an instance of a `Subclass` and not of its parent `Class`? ----> Same as question before.
- Are these allowed `Java` behaviors or is this maybe a bug related to `Android Studio` or `Dalvik` / `ART`? ----> Possibly.

Edit:

It seems that this is a bug for the debugger in Android Studio 1.4.

After debugging and testing with different devices I've found this:

- The error doesn't happen when not debugging the app.
- It also doesn't present when debugging or not on `Lollipop` devices.
- It has only been present when debugging `4.3` or `4.4` devices so far, if I unplug the device, the app behaves as expected.

As more information for the implementation, the try/catch block described before is inside an `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()`, and `someMethodThatThrowsExceptionA()` is a method constructs a query and calls internally a method that executes a `Fusiontables.Query.Sql` and throws `ExceptionA` , in this case `IOException` and it's subclass `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` (`ExceptionBthatExtendsExceptionA`) , so `Http` communications happen inside.

Also, when I try to catch the error inside `someMethodThatThrowsExceptionA()`, sometimes the `Exception` catched is not `null`, but it always ends up being `null` when I throw it again and catch it in the `catch block` of method that called `someMethodThatThrowsExceptionA()`.

Since the `Exception` is correctly interpreted as an instance of `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` (`ExceptionBthatExtendsExceptionA`) and the code enters into its corresponding `catch block`, the bug has to be happening after this and before the debugger figures out the value of the exception inside the block.

Comment: This happens when the exception propagated from called methods is not handled properly. check the method someMethodThatThrowsExceptionA() for the thrown exception.

Comment: Please post the content of someMethodThatThrowsExceptionA() method. It would be helpful.

Comment: `e` is not null. [This is not possible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18): "If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a null value, then an instance V' of class NullPointerException is created and thrown instead of null." Its *message* may be null. If `e` was null you couldn't catch it, and you couldn't throw it either.

Comment: Did you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400711/java-exception-itself-is-null

Comment: Thank you @Crusaderpyro , My concern is how was this situation possible regardless of the actual code I'm debugging now.

Comment: @VivekSingh Thank you. My question is not about the contents of my code, but on the possibility of null exceptions in Java/Android as a more general concern.

Comment: @EJP That is what I thought, but I'm on exactly that situation...

Comment: @Jozua Thank you, I'm checking this option now.

Comment: @buzoherbert The only way you can be 'on exactly that situation' is via a violation of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18), and therefore via a major platform bug. But it isn't plausible. How did the JVM know that `null` was an `Exception` as opposed to an `Error` or a `Throwable`. It simply is not plausible.

Comment: Can you please post the content of method from which exception is occurring or propagated.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the insight. I added more information based on your advice. It seems that this is a bug with Android Studio and some specific versions of Android and not something allowed by the Java specification.

Comment: "The error disappears when not debugging the app.". No. **The 'error' isn't present in the first place.** It is only an artefact of the debugger. It probably uses `Exception.toString()` to display the error. "The bug has to be happening after this and before the debugger figures out the value". No. The error happens **when** "the debugger figures out the value". To prove the 'error' realy exists you would have to show some *output* from the program that says so. Not just a debugger console. I spent most of yesterday fighting an erronous debugger display. They happen.