# Shortest code to throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, optimization, nullpointerexception

**Edit:**
Sorry about posting here instead of the codegolf stackexchange,
didn't heard of that before. 
Anyway thanks for the answers!

Okey, we all know the normal way to throw a NullPointerException in Java:

```
throw new NullPointerException(); // 33 characters
```

But I am searching for shorter (as in less characters) ways to do so.
The shortest I could get was

```
((Void)null).toString(); // 24 characters
```

How can we produce a java.lang.NullPointerException with even less code and without imports?

There must be a way!

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: this probably belongs on the codegolf stackexchange

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Well if this could be called in a method: `Area a;a.clone();`. Would be 17 Characters. (java.awt.geom.Area)

Comment: If this is "optimization", then you have a bizarre idea of what "optimal" means.

Comment: @Tom Won't compile: "The local variable may not have been initialized"

Comment: ((Byte)null).notify();

Comment: @JimGarrison ... mhh ... he didn't say, that the code should compile :P.

Comment: int a=(Byte)null; // 17 characters

Comment: That's not optimizing code, that's beeing lazy ^2

Comment: @Tom yes he did.  It can't throw an exception without compiling first.

Comment: Sorry about posting here instead of the codegolf stackexchange, didn't heard of that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now shortest way I know is by

```
throw null;//11 characters
```

You can find more info about it at [Why can I throw null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576922/why-can-i-throw-null-in-java)