# Why does throw null throw NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception

Why does this program compile?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw null;
    }
}
```

From 8.9.5 of the *C# Language Specification*,

> A `throw` statement with an expression throws the value produced by evaluating the expression. The expression must denote a value of the class type `System.Exception`, of a class type that derives from `System.Exception` or of a type parameter type that has `System.Exception` (or a subclass thereof) as its effective base class. If evaluation of the expression produces `null`, a `System.NullReferenceException` is thrown instead.

Obviously, `null` evaluates to `null`, so the last sentence is where this behavior is from, but how does it even get there? Attempting to throw other values that do not derive from `System.Exception` results in a compiler error, `error CS0155: The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception`.

---

The top answer on the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195764/why-does-c-sharp-allow-you-to-throw-null) begins with (emphasis mine):

> Because the language specification expects an expression of type `System.Exception` there (**therefore, `null` is a valid in that context**) ...

The expression `null is System.Exception` evaluates to false, and produces a compiler warning `warning CS0184: The given expression is never of the provided ('Exception') type`, so I'm comfortable making the assertion that `null` isn't valid where a `System.Exception` is required.

Comment: Because other values are *typed*. Null is not typed. Perhaps you could argue that you should have to write `throw (Exception)null;` - however, since you can pass `null` without explicitly specifying the type as an argument to `DoSomething(Exception ex)` - you should also be able to pass 'null' as an argument to `throw`

Comment: @Rob, Consider a method `static Type GetType<T>(T t) { return typeof (T); }`. You can pass it a null reference that is typed, i.e. `GetType((Exception)null)` and it performs like you'd expect. If you try to directly pass `null`, type inference can't determine the type being passed. Why doesn't the same kind of problem happen with `throw null`?

Comment: @jdphenix Well, that's specific to generics in C#. Since `null` is not typed, you need to provide a type that `T` can bind to. In the proposed duplicate (I'm not convinced it's a duplicate yet), it mentions that the check doesn't accomplish much, as you could still pass null indirectly (if a method were simply returning `null`). So explicitly preventing `throw null` doesn't seem to have any benefit in itself

Comment: @jdphenix to answer your edit, the proposed duplicate also quotes the ECMA spec which states: `System.NullReferenceException is thrown if obj is null.`

Comment: CIL allows objects of any type to be thrown, C# does not. The referenced ECMA specification addresses the former.